# SQL Server backup error. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2014

I have an azure drive mapped to SQL Server.

I have verified that SQL Server is using a service account called SQLBI and this account has SA access to the server and SQL Server and sees the azure drive which is mapped as the B drive.

When I try to backup to this drive using SQL Server, however, I get the following error.

Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot open backup device 'B:\SQL\test.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I see the drive in windows explorer, but for some reason, SQL Server does not.

Seems as if this is some sort of security issue but I can not resolve it.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: give sql server service account administrator privileges and see if that's a security issue

Comment: I have verified that this account already does indeed have admin privileges on both the server as well as SQL Server also which still does not resolve the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think that's a security issue in this case

Comment: I came across a very similar issue. The problem was SQL Server couldn't resolve mapped unit as explained [here](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-solve-operating-system-error-3) so I used the absolute network path.